# Open source implementations of video stabilization

Tags: video, video-processing

I am looking to implement a filter-based *O*( *n* log *n*) algorithm for stabilization of amateur video.

I believe this would be a useful tool for projects such as Witness.org.

I've searched for such a thing, and have found [Deshaker](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm) by Gunnar Thalin, and [Youtube's built-in editor feature](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2011/06/auto-directed-video-stabilization-with.html). These algorithms are not as efficient as I believe they could be.

Have I missed something? Are there other projects like this out there? Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Deshaker  is  not open source

Answer (score 2):

Cinelerra has a built-in video stabilizer plug-in.  It is difficult to master and does not correct the effects of a rolling shutter.  Youtube's stabilizer is much easier to use.

The source code for the Cinelerra plugin is [here](http://git.cinelerra.org/gitweb?p=CinelerraCV.git;a=tree;f=plugins/motion;h=45a464213982c0c6defce11d447c2b50bc874ff0;hb=HEAD):

Also have a look at [avisynthtrackin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avisynthtrackin/) and OpenCV and [this optical flow library](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/chzach/opensource.html).

Answer (score 2):

FFMpeg has a deshaker AVfilter that is fast and simple. There’s also vid.stab, but that is more compute intense.

Answer (score 0):

The Blender team (or actually a GSOC student I think) are working on 2D tracking, which can be used for stabilization. See http://lesterbanks.com/2011/06/using-blender-for-2d-image-stabilization/